# Diagram of particle collision in center of mass frame

Tags: diagrams

I'm studying Feynman diagrams and I want to draw the particle interaction in the center of mass frame to visualize the kinematics of the situation. How can I draw this in a quick way? I'm thinking of using the tikz package since I'm a bit familiar to it when drawing Feynman diagrams. But I have no idea on how to begin a drawing which is not such a diagram

Any help is appreciated! I'm really in the dark on how to draw simple (in)elastic collisions...

Something like the image on the left here
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [tikz-feynman package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)?

Comment: @SandyG yes I am familiar with that package. My question is about basic classical particle collisions, not feynman diagrams

Comment: Could you provide a diagram? Even a hand-drawn one would help. As it stands your question may not be answered since it's not clear (to non-physicists) what you want.

Comment: @SandyG diagram is posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

[image: result]

#### Strategy

- use `\pic`, which is a kind of macro for `Tikz`-pathes
- design 3 `\pic`s for the `xy`-system, `com`-frame and `lab`-frame
- place them as needed

#### Documentclass and packages/libraries

- using `standalone` is nicer for development
- `arrows.meta` lets you modify arrow tips, or use predefined ones
- `angles` and `quotes` are needed to draw and label angles

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% nicer for development
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                    % provides arrow tips etc.
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}                  % to draw angles
```

#### xy-pic

All `\pic`s are defined in the style section, here at the beginning of the `tikzpicture`. You can also use `\tikzset` instead.

Inside a pic-statement you just draw, i.e. put a set of path statements. Think of having your own canvas available, i.e. just reference coordinates as you would do in any other `tikzpicture`. When placing `\pic`s, `Tikz` will use the correct absolute positions.

Besides drawing a line through 3 points, with arrows at both ends, this path also contains two nodes, putting axis labels, shifted as needed, BEFORE this path ends with `;`

Kindly watch the comma `,` at the end, as these pics are defined in the style section.

```
    xy/.pic={   % the coordinate system
        \draw[<->] (1,0) node[xshift=1.5mm] {x} -- (0,0) 
                    -- node[yshift=1.5mm] {y} (0,1);
    },
```

#### lab-pic

Same idea, with some more content.

The coordinates are useful to draw angles later: these need 3 coordinates.

The vectors are just lines, with one arrow tip, placing labels again. I could have used a coordinate for (-1.4,0), but simply didn't. `above` shifts the nodes text above the path, while `pos=.4` or `midway == pos.5` move it along the path to be drawn. For V'2 it was useful to use a shift in polar coordinates.

The angles are just a special `\pic`, where you can specify how they will look like. Most important is to get the order of the 3 points right.

For convenience I integrated the title with the `lab`-`\pic`. This may or may not be a good idea, as this way you'll need to readjust their positions, when you change the vectors.

```
    lab/.pic={  % the lab-frame
        % ~~~ most needed coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);   % the point of collision 
        \coordinate (B) at (40:1.3);    % V'1 
        \coordinate (C) at (-50:1.3);   % V'2
        \coordinate (D) at (15mm,0);    % end point of reference line
        % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[->]   (-1.4,0) -- node[above,midway] {$\vec{V_1}$} (A);   
        \draw[->]   (A)      -- node[above,pos=.4] {$\vec{V'_1}$} (B);  
        \draw[->]   (A)      -- node[shift=(230:3mm),pos=.4] {$\vec{V'_2}$} (C);    
        \draw[dotted]   (A) -- (D);
        % ~~~ angles ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \pic[draw,<->,angle radius=7mm,"$\psi$"]    {angle={D--A--B}};
        \pic[draw,<->,angle radius=8mm,"$\zeta$"]   {angle={C--A--D}};
        % ~~~ title ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         \node at (0,2) {laboratory frame};
    },
```

#### com-pic

Nothing new here, besides coordinate `(A1)`, which is slightly shifted to the right, and some minor fine tuning on the titles position.

#### Putting your intended drawing together

Now, all you need to do is to place the 3 `\pic`s.

```
    % ~~~ intended overall drawing ~~~~~~~~~
    \pic at (0  ,0) {xy};
    \pic at (3.5,0) {com};
    \pic at (7,  0) {lab};
```

#### Demonstrating the potential

Now you can place as many copies of the 3 pics as you need. E.g. you can even rotate it, change its color, and keep the shapes intact.

```
    % ~~~ demonstrating the potential ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \pic[rotate=-30,transform shape,red!80!blue!90] at (4,-5) {lab};
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% nicer for development
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                    % provides arrow tips etc.
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}                  % to draw angles

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Stealth},              % overwriting default tip   
    xy/.pic={   % the coordinate system
        \draw[<->] (1,0) node[xshift=1.5mm] {x} -- (0,0) 
                    -- node[yshift=1.5mm] {y} (0,1);
    },
    lab/.pic={  % the lab-frame
        % ~~~ most needed coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);   % the point of collision 
        \coordinate (B) at (40:1.3);    % V'1 
        \coordinate (C) at (-50:1.3);   % V'2
        \coordinate (D) at (15mm,0);    % end point of reference line
        % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[->]   (-1.4,0) -- node[above,midway] {$\vec{V_1}$} (A);   
        \draw[->]   (A)      -- node[above,pos=.4] {$\vec{V'_1}$} (B);  
        \draw[->]   (A)      -- node[shift=(230:3mm),pos=.4] {$\vec{V'_2}$} (C);    
        \draw[dotted]   (A) -- (D);
        % ~~~ angles ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \pic[draw,<->,angle radius=7mm,"$\psi$"]    {angle={D--A--B}};
        \pic[draw,<->,angle radius=8mm,"$\zeta$"]   {angle={C--A--D}};
        % ~~~ title ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         \node at (0,2) {laboratory frame};
    },
    com/.pic={  % center of mass frame
        % ~~~ most needed coordinates ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \coordinate (A)  at (0,0);      % the point of collision 
        \coordinate (B)  at (40:13mm);  % v'1 
        \coordinate (A1) at (.2,0);     % slightly shifted towards the right    
        \coordinate (C)  at (230:13mm); % v'2
        \coordinate (D)  at (1.5,0);    % 
        % ~~~ vectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[->]       (-1.3,0) -- node[above,midway] {$\vec{v_1}$} (A);
        \draw[->]       (A) -- node[above,pos=.4] {$\vec{v'_1}$} (B);   
        \draw[->]       (D) -- node[below,pos=.35] {$\vec{v_2}$} (A1);
        \draw[->]       (A1) -- node[right,pos=.5] {$\vec{v'_2}$} (C);  
        % ~~~ angle ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \pic[draw,<->,angle radius=9mm,"$\theta$"]  {angle={D--A--B}};
        % ~~~ title ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         \node at (0,2.05) {center of mass frame};
    },
 ]
    % ~~~ intended overall drawing ~~~~~~~~~
    \pic at (0  ,0) {xy};
    \pic at (3.5,0) {com};
    \pic at (7,  0) {lab};
    
    % ~~~ demonstrating the potential ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \pic[rotate=-30,transform shape,red!80!blue!90] at (4,-5) {lab};

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted?